# Trying to run safe-infrastructure locally

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

My goal is to run the safe-infrastructure service for a sample test by following the Guide to run our services locally.

I am trying to add polygon-zkEVM chain but the service isn't working.

**PROBLEM**

for the following endpoint
`http://localhost:8000/cgw/v1/chains/1101/safes/0xB004E7c48B476b71590b5cc08ab6E44F0EFcA1A9`

I am getting this error
`{"code":1337,"message":"Could not generate value"}`

[image]
I am able to deploy the new safe using UI but not able to add the existing safe or index the new safe.

Following is the chain details i have added

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "chainId": "1101",
            "chainName": "Cherry",
            "shortName": "cherry",
            "description": "Polygon zkEVM mainnet chain",
            "l2": true,
            "rpcUri": {
                "authentication": "NO_AUTHENTICATION",
                "value": "https://zkevm-rpc.com"
            },
            "safeAppsRpcUri": {
                "authentication": "NO_AUTHENTICATION",
                "value": "https://zkevm-rpc.com"
            },
            "publicRpcUri": {
                "authentication": "NO_AUTHENTICATION",
                "value": "https://zkevm-rpc.com"
            },
            "blockExplorerUriTemplate": {
                "address": "https://zkevm.polygonscan.com/address/{{address}}",
                "txHash": "https://zkevm.polygonscan.com/tx/{{txHash}}",
                "api": "https://zkevm.polygonscan.com/api?module={{module}}&action={{action}}&address={{address}}&apiKey={{apiKey}}"
            },
            "nativeCurrency": {
                "name": "Ether",
                "symbol": "ETH",
                "decimals": 18,
                "logoUri": "/media/chains/1101/currency_logo.png"
            },
            "transactionService": "http://nginx:8000/txs",
            "vpcTransactionService": "http://nginx:8000/txs",
            "theme": {
                "textColor": "#ffffff",
                "backgroundColor": "#9463FA"
            },
            "gasPrice": [],
            "ensRegistryAddress": null,
            "recommendedMasterCopyVersion": "1.3.0",
            "disabledWallets": [],
            "features": []
        }
    ]
}
```

**All the safe details with statuses are already populated in the txs service**

**Safe Statuses**
[image]

**Master Copy**
[image]

**Proxy Factories**
[image]

Comment: Could you post the result of calling the url: /api/v1/safes/<safe-address-checksummed>/ ? for the tx-service url?

Comment: {
"address": "0xB004E7c48B476b71590b5cc08ab6E44F0EFcA1A9",
"nonce": null,
"threshold": null,
"owners": null,
"masterCopy": "0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E",
"modules": [],
"fallbackHandler": "0xf48f2B2d2a534e402487b3ee7C18c33Aec0Fe5e4",
"guard": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"version": "1.3.0+L2"
}

Comment: That Safe looks not initialized and that might be the issue. Could you create a Safe using the UI?

Comment: This was the safe created from UI 

{
"address": "0xC153D05B3987f100EAA0Ce54691e04aA2828c4AF",
"nonce": null,
"threshold": null,
"owners": null,
"masterCopy": "0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E",
"modules": [],
"fallbackHandler": "0xf48f2B2d2a534e402487b3ee7C18c33Aec0Fe5e4",
"guard": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"version": "1.3.0+L2"
}

but same issue

Comment: Ok, then something must be off for that chain, as `owners`, `threshold` and `nonce` can never be `null`

Comment: But these details are there in the transaction service.You can see the Safe Statuses Screenshot above

Comment: I think i have found the issue. this network doesn't support Multicall
```Multicall not supported for this network```

Comment: Multicall is not an issue. We found out that the contracts don't appear to be deployed on zk polygon: https://zkevm.polygonscan.com/address/0xB004E7c48B476b71590b5cc08ab6E44F0EFcA1A9

But indeed they are on goerli:
https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xB004E7c48B476b71590b5cc08ab6E44F0EFcA1A9